# When can we expect moderator elections?

Tags: support, moderation

This is the very first private beta I participate in. From what I understand, it takes about (sometimes more) a week for it to be a public beta.

When are moderators for it elected? During public beta? After it airs as an ordinary site?

Comment: Woah, a little quick there, no?  We need pro tems first.

Comment: @casperOne: That's why I asked, I don't know the process, and want to learn more about it :)

Comment: Fair enough, I forget not everyone knows how things run on SE from the get go.  Carry on =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators are *appointed* a few weeks into public beta (by us, the Stack Exchange Inc. [Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do)); if/when the site graduates, there'll be an actual election where folks nominate themselves and other folks vote for them.

### See:

- [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)
- [Stack Exchange Moderator Elections Begin](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/)
- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this older blogpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), sometime around 7 days into a beta, moderators are selected.

If I understand correctly, until that point, we get a bit of extra attention from the global moderators.